# PDO transaction with multiple models

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, transactions

How could I make a transaction using multiple php controllers to make the queries?

Currently, my code is like this (A bit more complex, but I am not allowed to show anymore)

```
$operation = new Operations();
$bill = new Bills();
$employee = new Employee();

$operation->setName("Name");
$operationCreated = $operation->create();
$result = "";

if($operationCreated){

    $bill->setAmount(1000);
    $billCreated = $bill->create();

    if($billCreated){

        $employee->setName("Name");
        $result= $employee->create();
    }
}

return $result;
```

The way it is right now leads to a problem where I might have an operation created well, but no billing and no employee and my database ends with a row I don't want because I don't have all the information I need in the database.

I need a way to revert the changes if any one of them fails, and I think a transaction would do the trick, but I don't know how can be done. All three classes extend the Database class that has the create() method.

Comment: Well .. top extending database class. When you write `class Empleyee extends Databases`, it reads as "every user is a special case of database" ... with obviously is stupid.

Comment: Also, those are not "models". By the look of it, what you have are [active record](https://w.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) instances.

Comment: Things were already like that when I was told to solve this issue. This code is inside a 'controller' which instances those 'models'. I never faced this sort of thing  (or any oop php for that matter) that's why I need some help